# Existence of a homogeneous system of parameters

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, invariant-theory

In the book on invariant theory by Sturmfels, it is stated that every finitely generated graded $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $R$, of finite Krull dimension $n$, has a homogeneous system of parameters. Moreover, it is said that this homogeneous system of parameters always will be algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.

There are two problems I did not manage to solve. It is clear that by Noether's normalization lemma there always exists $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ in $R$ such that $R$ is finitely generated as a module over $\mathbb{C}[r_1,\ldots,r_n]$. Although it seems very clear to me, I can not find a rigid argument why these $r_1,\ldots, r_n$ should be algebraically independent. I would like to avoid Nakayama's lemma, because I totally have the feeling it should be possible to proof without invoking it.

Secondly, I do not understand how one can conclude that there always exists a homogeneous system of parameters, by the existence of the $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ as in Noether's normalization lemma.

Any help is welcome!

Note: A homogeneous system of parameters for $R$ is a set of homogeneous elements $\theta_1,\ldots, \theta_n$ such that $R$ as a module over the subring $\mathbb{C}[\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n]$ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question:** Why are the $r_i$'s algebraically independent?

Algebraic independence is sometimes taken as part of the definition of a system of parameters guaranteed by the Noether normalization lemma, but since you are working from a statement of the theorem that does not make this explicit, let me show you why finiteness of $R$ over $\mathbb{C}[r_1,\dots,r_n]$ does actually imply the $r_i$'s are algebraically independent. The key thing is that $n$ is both the number of $r_i$'s and also the Krull dimension of $R$.

Let $r_1,\dots,r_n$ be the elements guaranteed by the Noether normalization lemma such that $R$ is finitely generated as a module over $S:=\mathbb{C}[r_1,\dots,r_n]\subset R$. By assumption, $R$ has Krull dimension $n$. Since finiteness of $R$ over $S$ implies $R$ is integral over $S$ (see Proposition 5.1 in [Atiyah-MacDonald](https://wstein.org/edu/Fall2003/252/references/Atiyah-MacDonald/Atiyah-McDonald-Commutative_Algebra.pdf)), and integrality preserves dimension (proof in appendix below), it follows that $S$ has Krull dimension $n$. Since it is already generated by the $n$ elements $r_1,\dots,r_n$, they must be algebraically independent. We can see this as follows.

Let $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ be the polynomial ring. There is a canonical surjection $\phi:\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_n]\rightarrow S$ obtained by mapping $X_i\mapsto r_i$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$. Any nontrivial algebraic relation between the $r_i$'s would show up as a nontrivial element of the kernel of $\phi$; thus our job is to show that the kernel of $\phi$ is trivial. Suppose for a contradiction that there existed a nonzero polynomial $F\in \ker\phi$. Let $\mathfrak{p}_0\subset\dots\subset \mathfrak{p}_d$ be a maximal chain of prime ideals of $S$. The fact that $S$ is dimension $n$ means that $d=n$. But on the other hand, $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}_0)\supset \ker \phi\ni F$, so the inclusion $(0)\subset \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}_0)$ is strict. It follows that $(0)\subset \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}_0)\subset\dots\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}_d)$ is a chain of primes of length $d+1$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, which has Krull dimension $n$, and therefore $d+1\leq n$. This contradiction proves the nonexistence of $F$, so $\phi$ is injective, and this means the $r_i$'s are algebraically independent.

**Second question:** Why can the $r_i$'s be taken to be homogeneous?

Strong versions of the Noether normalization lemma exist which explicitly say that if the ring is graded then you can take the $r_i$'s to be homogeneous. For example, Theorem 13.3 in [Eisenbud's book](http://www.math.ens.fr/%7Ebenoist/refs/Eisenbud.pdf), which is even stronger than you need. (See also Lemma 13.2, where much of the work of the proof is done.) The statement is this:

> **Theorem 13.3** (Noether Normalization). Let $R$ be an affine ring of dimension $d$ over a field $k$. If $I_1\subset\dots\subset I_m$ is a chain of ideals of $R$ with $\dim I_j = d_j$ and $d_1>d_2>\dots>d_m\geq 0$, then $R$ contains a polynomial ring $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_d]$ in such a way that $R$ is a finitely generated $S$-module and
>
> $$ I_j\cap S = (x_{d_i+1},\dots,x_d), \;\forall j=1,\dots,m.$$
>
> If the ideals $I_j$ are homogeneous, then the $x_i$ may be chosen to be homogeneous. If $k$ is infinite, and $R$ is generated over $k$ by $y_1,\dots, y_r$, then for $j\leq d_m$ the element $x_j$ may be chosen to be a $k$-linear combination of the $y_i$.

To apply this statement in your situation, present your $R$ as $T/I$ where $T=\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_\ell]$ is a polynomial ring and $I$ is a homogeneous ideal. This is possible because $R$ is a finitely generated graded algebra over $\mathbb{C}$; note that the $X_i$'s might need to be assigned degrees other than 1, but this is okay because tracing through Eisenbud's proof shows that the theorem stated here doesn't require a *standard* grading on the polynomial ring. Then apply Theorem 13.3 to the ring $T$ with the ideal $I_1=I$ (and $m=1$). The conclusion of the theorem supplies you with a subring $S'=\mathbb{C}[R_1,\dots,R_\ell]$, with each $R_i\in T$ homogeneous, such that $I\cap S' = (R_{n+1},\dots,R_\ell)$ and $T$ is finite over $S'$. Thus the canonical homomorphism $\pi:T\rightarrow T/I=R$ maps $R_1,\dots,R_n$ to homogeneous elements $r_1,\dots,r_n\in R$, and $R_{n+1},\dots,R_\ell$ are mapped to zero. Let $S\subset R$ be the image of $S'$ under $\pi$. Then $S=\mathbb{C}[r_1,\dots,r_n]$, and $T/I=R$ is finite over $S'/(S'\cap I) = S$ because it is generated as an $S$-module by the images of $S'$-module generators for $T$ under $\pi$.

**Appendix: proof that integrality preserves dimension**

Let $R/S$ be an integral extension of commutative, unital rings. Take a maximal chain of prime ideals in $R$ and intersect with $S$ to produce a chain of primes of equal length in $S$; they are distinct by the incomparability theorem [Corollary 5.9 in Atiyah-MacDonald]; thus $\dim R\leq \dim S$. Take a maximal chain of prime ideals in $S$ and lift the bottom one to $R$ by the lying-over theorem [Theorem 5.10 in A-M]; then lift the rest of the chain to $R$ by the going-up theorem [Theorem 5.11 in A-M]; thus $\dim R\geq \dim S$.